# Regex to find and append every <img> tag except the first one

Tags: php, html, regex

In PHP, I have a chunk of HTML and I'm trying to figure out how to find and append every image tag EXCEPT the first one with a span. The below code works, but it appends ALL img tags. I need it to ignore the first instance of img:

```
$html = preg_replace("#(<img.*?>)#", "$1<span class=\"blah\">blah</span>", $html);
```

Comment: You could use an HTML or XML parse for this it'd probably be more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

Try with [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
$str = "<img><img><img><img>";

$str = preg_replace_callback('/<img[^>]*>/', function ($m) use (&$rcheck){
  return (!isset($rcheck) && $rcheck=true) ? $m[0] : $m[0]."<span>";
}, $str);

echo $str;
```

The idea is to use a check variable for skipping first `<img>`. [Try it at eval.in](https://eval.in/371544)

```
<img><img><span><img><span><img><span>
```

Comment: This works above, but I actually need to append a string that is stored in a variable. So instead of -- $m[0]."<span>" ... something more like -- $m[0].$mySpan -- And when I try to do that, and every variation I can think of, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a negative lookahead:

```
(?!^)(<img.*?>)
```

[regex101.com example](https://regex101.com/r/hO4zQ1/1)

Comment: Could you update your question with an example of what you would like to see as the output?